# Why does 'f' is not defined?

Tags: python

I new to Python and I'm following [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation) tutorial about files handling.

If you scroll down you can see **How to close a file using Python** and under it he is using `try` and `finally`,
my problem is that in my program, I'm getting an error: **'f' is not defined**.

Why am I getting this problem ? Did I missed something ?

**Example:**

```
try:
   f = open("test.txt",encoding = 'utf-8')
finally:
   f.close()
```

And I don't want a good book to start with.

Comment: Always use `with` statement when dealing with files.

Comment: I got a `Name 'f' can be not defned` in my case, are you sure to get `f not defined` ?

Comment: @azro I don't understand you.

Comment: If the file you try to open doesn't exist, `f` won't be defined, and you'll get this error in the `finally` block. This is not a good coding example, and the whole chapter of the tutorial shouldn't be used anymore. The 'right' way to work with files has been to use `with open('test.txt') as f:` for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you may have is `Name 'f' can be not defined`, because if an error is raised during the `open` method, you'll never assign `f` and so it won't be defined in the `finally`. A solution would be to assign to another value before :

```
f = None
try:
    f = open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8')
except FileNotFoundError as fnfe:
    print("File not found")
    exit(10)
finally:
    if f:
        f.close()
```

But as this syntax if not very nie, you may use the `with` statement, that auto-close the object when you go out of the block, but be sure to catch the `FileNotFoundError`

```
try:
    with open("test.txt",encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
       # perform file operations
except FileNotFoundError as fnfe:
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: This whole construct seems off to me. You should have `with open()` inside a `try`. The first block is not best practice, and the second approach will still fail if the file isn't found (regardless of whether there is an exception in the `with` block)

Comment: The error I have is: `name 'f' is not defined` but ok.

Comment: And the first solution is not working, `No such file or directory: 'test.txt'` It still need to find the file even if you use `try:`

Comment: @nakE add an `except ` like me, your path is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You better use the following syntax:

```
with open("test.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:

    # Do something with f
```

There is no need to close it, `with` does that for you.

Comment: @azro there is no way to fix the OP's code other than this... Or just using `except` and skipping the issue

Comment: @roganjosh look at my answer, there is but it's not nice

Comment: @Tomerikoo the answer has been edited,  my comment was relevant to a sentence that is no longer part of the actual answer